# How do I set the initial content of a TinyMCE editor in ASP.NET MVC4 (Razor)?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, tinymce

I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/tinymce-html-text-editior-and-asp-net-mvc-setting-it-up-has-become-easy-with-nuget) for grabbing TinyMCE via nuget and using it with Razor in MVC4.

All works well, but when my form loads, I need to place some default text in the TinyMCE control.

How do I do that?

The problem for me is that I am using Razor (which I normally don't do) and everything is abstracted (e.g. `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Message)`).  I can't see any "hooks" into TinyMCE that would let me set the content before the page renders.

Answer (score 1):

Got it sorted--You have to set the value in the controller.  So if you have this in your view:

```
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Message)
```

Then you need this in your controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var someValue = "foo"; //Get your data here
            var model = new CorporateAccountModel {Message = someValue};
            return View(model);
        }
```

That's it.  No additional coding is required in the view, which makes me a little uncomfortable but works.